# Create vector with increasing variance

Tags: r, function, vector

The hand drawn plot below shows residuals plotted against fitted values from a poisson regression.

How can I create two vectors, that when plotted, show the same pattern as in attached plot?

Note that it doesn't matter what the fitted values are (hence no scale).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]Make the standard deviation of y an increasing function of x:

```
x <- runif(100, 0, 10)
y <- rnorm(100, 0, x)
plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my try (translating the Stata code from http://www.econometricsbysimulation.com/2012/11/modeling-heteroskedasticity.html to R):

```
set.seed(123)

# Let's generate a sample data set that has heteroskedasticity in z.
z  <- runif(1000)*5

# This means the standard deviation on u is 18 plus 16*z (which has a mean of 2.5)
u  <-  ((18+16*z))*rnorm(1000)

# Plot
plot(z, u)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take a sequence, take sine of the sequence and multiply it by sequence itself.

```
a = seq(1:1000)
b = sin(a) * a
plot(b)
```

You will have a single vector which has an increasing variance. You can use it to create a time series or anything else you like.
[image]